# Any tool to go from java code to jHipster templates?

Tags: jhipster

Since the generated java code doesn't fit all my needs, I would need to modify the templates (mainly in server). Small modifications are pretty straightforward but I was wondering if there is some tool to go from existing java code to this template.

Answer (score 0):

We did [modules](https://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace/#/list) for this use case, and I even did some specific ones for some clients. So this would be my favorite solution.

Then, I clearly see in our stats that many people are forking JHipster and modifying it - this is probably easier at first sight, but of course you'll have trouble when we release new versions, as you will have to sync your code with each new release.